# Android Camera Intent reopen issue after capture image from system camera and press save button

Tags: android, android-camera

I use the following code for capture image form system camera in my android application. But when I capture image successfully and press save/ok button for redirecting to my activity but again camera reopen. When I capture image 2-3 time and press ok/save then I redirected to my activity. So which problem occur?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Presumably, there is a bug in the camera app that your `Intent` happens to start.

Comment: Finally I solved this problem. I Remove the screenOrientation="portrait" from AndroidManifest.xml for that particular class. Because In some phone when we call the system camera, screen orientation auto change to "landscape" and when we return to our Activity, it will try to change our app screen portrait to landscape and reload the class. So every time reload and open camera.